Max of sums of independent elements in two n-tuples
Let $X_{1}, ..., X_{n}, Y_{1}, ..., Y_{n}$ be independent random variables with finite expectation. Assume that for $1 \leq i \leq n$, it is the case that $X_{i}$ is equal in distribution to $Y_{i}$ (that is r.v.'s sharing the same index have the same distribution). Fix any $\sigma \in S_{n}$. Is it true that:
$\mathbb{E}(\max\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} \{X_{i}+Y_{i} \}) \geq \mathbb{E}(\max\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} \{X_{i} + Y_{\sigma(i)} \})$?
I asked a similar question without the assumption that $X_{i}$ were independent of one another, and the statement was not true, but if we add independence, does this work? Thank you

Your earlier question seems to have been https://mathoverflow.net/questions/473213/expectation-of-maxima-of-random-functions

Try this with just $n=2$ and $\sigma = (12)$ being the transposition of $1$ and $2$.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer
Honestly still not even clear to me in this case:
$$\mathbb{E}( \max { (X_{1}+Y_{1}), (X_{2}+Y_{2}) } ) \geq \mathbb{E}( \max { (X_{1}+Y_{2}), (X_{2}+Y_{1}) })$$
Given $X_{i} =^{d} Y_{i}$ and all r.v.s are independent?
Clearly it's true (with equality) for example if $X_{1} =^{d} X_{2}$. Or if $X_{1}, X_{2}$ are constant, and it seems true for what other examples I've tried, but how to prove this?
Also, yes thank you Henry
